# Bypass .htaccess login when user has a specific cookie SetEnvIf

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cookies, xampp

This is how my .htaccess looks like:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "FORBIDDEN AREA"
AuthUserfile "../htdocs/site/.htpasswd"
AuthGroupFile /
Require valid-user

#Allow valid-user
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
SetEnvIf HTTP_COOKIE my_cookie_name norequire
Allow from env=norequire
Satisfy any
```

My user has a cookie, and if his cookie has a name "my_cookie_name" I would like that he bypasses the .htaccess login (authentication) so that he doesn't need to enter his username and password. I tried with SetEnvIF but it does't seem to work, or am I doing something wrong. If anyone has some suggestion I would be grateful to hear it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Cookie PHPSESSID=.* PASS=1

AuthType Basic
AuthName "FORBIDDEN AREA"
AuthUserfile "../htdocs/site/.htpasswd"
AuthGroupFile /
Require valid-user

#Allow valid-user
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=PASS
Satisfy any
```

Comment: I tried it but it won't work, always, asks for user/pass. The cookie has a name: "my_cookie_name", and a value: "5".

Comment: still same, i also put "allow from my_ip" and it still asked for username/pass, maybe it's something with httpd.conf

Comment: How is this cookie getting created?

Comment: `<?php
  $date_of_expiry = time() + 60*60*60 ;
  setcookie( "my_cookie_name ","5", $date_of_expiry);
?>`

Comment: well, it seems that this works fine with IE, and firefox after restart (and going again to private browsing) - so it's solved, it seems my browser remembered some old settings, thanks

Comment: Ah that's right, you need to restart browser to make it forget old auth sessions.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it worked out for you.

Comment: I'll accept it for Your dedication :) But this is working fine:
`AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Login"
AuthUserfile "../htdocs/site/.htpasswd"
AuthGroupFile "/dev/null"
SetEnvIf Cookie PHPSESSID=.* PASS=1
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=PASS
Require valid-user
Satisfy any`

Comment: Thanks and I have updated answer to help out future readers on SO.

Comment: Where's the name of the cookie in this answer? Does this allow ANY cookie to bypass basic auth?

Comment: Check the SetEnvIfNoCase line that is checking a specific cookie to set env variable